# Unable to extract values from a list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which is something like below

```
data = [("patient 1", 0.44), ("patient 2", 0.14), ("patient 3", 0.22)]
```

So I need to create a list of first values of every tuple. So this is what I do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data))
values = df.iloc[:, 0].unique()
```

So I get an expected list which looks like below

```
['patient 1', 'patient 2', 'patient 3']
```

But sometimes my dataset might have some missing values. So it maybe something like this

```
data = [("patient 1", 0.44), ("patient 2", 0.14), ("patient 3",)]
```

As you can see, the value for `patient 3` is empty or None. So when I run the above program again, instead of getting the list of first values of every tuple, I get the original list as it is

```
[('patient 1', 0.44), ('patient 2', 0.14), ('patient 3',)]
```

How do I ensure that despite the data being incomplete, I get the list I want since I only want the first values of each tuple?

**Note:** I know I can use simple python to extract first values but since the data set can be very big, I want to stick to `Pandas` to get the result.

Comment: Your first solution should work.  Did you try it?

Comment: @Using pandas I get the same list back when data set is incomplete.

Comment: What did you want to get back?  I get the results I thought you were expecting.  Meaning, there isn't anything wrong

Comment: @piRSquared as mentioned in the question, the first value of every tuple from the list of tuples. So essentially this `['patient 1', 'patient 2', 'patient 3']`. I do not get this when there are one or more tuples with the second value being empty.

Comment: Try `pd.Series(data).str[0]`

Comment: Use `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` to make the dataframe.

Comment: Ahh!  I missed that you were calling `pd.DataFrame(np.array(data))`  Yeah that'll mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

You could clean your data. Here is an example of how you could do it :

```
data = [("patient 1", 0.44), ("patient 2", 0.14), ("patient 3",)]

# We check if there are two values in the tuple otherwise we discard it
cleaned_data = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in data if len(x)>1]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(cleaned_data ))
values = df.iloc[:, 0].unique()
```

---

Output :

```
array(['patient 1', 'patient 2'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Is it possible to discard such incomplete tuples altogether:? So then the data set becomes `[("patient 1", 0.44), ("patient 2", 0.14)]`

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer so it discards incomplete tuples :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).fillna('')[0].values
```

Hope this helps.